# output array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am going nuts here.

```
$val = array(2,3,4,8);

$names = array();
$q = mysql_query("SELECT x FROM y WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$val).")");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  $names[$row['id']] = $row['tName'];
}
```

The above works fine.
Below i will then create a foreach loop:

```
foreach($val as $values) {
  print $names[$values]."<br>";
}
```

The above will output only ONE result, even though $val = array(1,2,3,4);

print_r($names); returns all data, both inside, outside, before and after foreach.

Am i missing something here ?

EDIT:

Result of print_r:

```
Array ( [2] => textA [3] => textB [4] => textC [8] => textD )
```

Comment: please show the result of `print_r($names);` I expect that the ids dont match those in your `$val` array

Comment: The IDS match fine, i have compared it all and everything is as it should be. However it sill will only ouput one result when printing $names[$values];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my brilliance i created the $val array like this:

```
$val = $_GET['val'];
$val = str_replace("[","",$val);
$val = str_replace("]","",$val);
$val = str_replace("\"","",$val);
$val = explode(",",$val);
```

The $_GET['val'] data is jquery generated (["1","2","3","4"]).

That was the issue. The solution was ofcourse to use json_decode:

```
json_decode($_GET['val'])
```

My apologies for not seing that (and mentioning it)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

```
foreach($names as $key=>$val)
{
     echo $val."<br/>";
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
foreach($names as $key=>$val)
{
     echo $names[$key]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not $names that i need looped, but $val. Inside the loop i then need the names from $names

Answer (score 0):

I think the `foreach` loop should be this way

```
foreach($names as $key=>$name)
{  
     echo $name."<br>";
}

OR

foreach($names as $name)
{  
     echo $name['id']."<br>";
}
```

this will output all the result

Answer (score 0):

I also have came from this situation and this worked for me,hope for you also:

```
   $val = array(1,2,3,4);
   $names[] = array();//add this declaration
   foreach($val as $values){
       print $names[$values];
   }
```

Thank you